# Initializing `attr_accessor`-like method with history

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name
    attr_reader attr_name + "_history"
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{attr_name}=(new_value)
        @#{attr_name}_history = [nil] if @#{attr_name}_history.nil?
        @#{attr_name}_history << @#{attr_name} = new_value
      end
    }
  end
end

class Example
  attr_accessor_with_history :foo
  attr_accessor_with_history :bar
end
```

There is `Class.attr_accessor_with_history` method that provides the same
functionality as `attr_accessor` but also tracks every value the attribute has
ever had.

```
> a = Example.new; a.foo = 2; a.foo = "test"; a.foo_history
=> [nil, 2, "test"]
```

But,

```
> a = Example.new; a.foo_history
=> nil
```

and it should be `[nil`.

How can I define single `initialize` method for `Example` class where each
`…_history` value will be initialize as `[nil]`?

Comment: Where is this "attr_accessor_with_history" problem from? It's [appeared many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=attr_accessor_with_history).

Comment: It's from very first homework in «Software Engineering for Software as a Service» course on Coursera.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: yeah, and it seems that I even answered a couple of them. But then forgot :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, your best bet is to define a custom reader for history (along with your custom writer).

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{attr_name}_history
        @#{attr_name}_history || [nil] # give default value if not assigned
      end

      def #{attr_name}=(new_value)
        @#{attr_name}_history ||= [nil] # shortcut, compare to your line
        @#{attr_name}_history << @#{attr_name} = new_value
      end
    }
  end
end

class Example
  attr_accessor_with_history :foo
  attr_accessor_with_history :bar
end

a = Example.new; a.foo = 2; a.foo = "test"; 
a.foo_history # => [nil, 2, "test"]

a = Example.new
a.foo_history # => [nil]
```

### Edit:

Here's a slightly more verbose snippet, but it doesn't use `class_eval` (which is frowned upon, when used without necessity).

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name

    define_method "#{attr_name}_history" do
      instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}_history") || [nil]
    end

    define_method "#{attr_name}=" do |new_value|
      v = instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}_history")
      v ||= [nil]
      v << new_value

      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}_history", v)
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", new_value)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what was in the original post :)

Comment: but i know you can write better one))

Comment: i have changed my answer, i hope you like it more, at least it works))

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: can you also add examples (like in my first snippet), which I can copy/paste/run? :)

Comment: At first i didn't understand why did you provide your answers as full snippets, now i know. Edited my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Sloves in one class_eval

`class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s 
    attr_reader attr_name
    attr_reader attr_name+"_history"
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{attr_name}=(val)
        if @#{attr_name}_history
          @#{attr_name}_history << @#{attr_name}
        else
          @#{attr_name}_history = [nil]
        end
        @#{attr_name} = val
      end
    }
  end
end`

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.